# Jest timeouts when trying to test with jasmine-pit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, jestjs

I'm trying to use Jest to run a small test against an angular UI but I'm getting a timeout after 5 seconds.
Here's my code:

```
jest.autoMockOff();

require('../../../../bower_components/angular/angular');
require('../../../../bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks');

window.Event = {};

describe('about', function(){

   var mockScope;

   pit('updates the view ', function(done){
        return runTest()
       .then(function(){
           var $ = require('../../../../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery');
           expect($("#about-div").text()).toEqual('fred');  
       });
    });

    function runTest() {
       var q = require('../../../../bower_components/q/q');
       var defer = q.defer();

       require('../../../../app/scripts/app');
       require('../../../../app/scripts/controllers/about');

       angular.mock.module('app');
       inject(function($rootScope, $controller){
          mockScope = $rootScope.$new();
          controller = $controller('aboutController', {$scope: mockScope});
       });

       document.body.innerHTML =
            '<html>' +
            '   <body>' +
            '      <div ng-controller="aboutController">' +
            '         <div id="about-div" >{{firstName}}</div>' +
            '      </div>' +
            '   </body>' + 
            '</html>';

       setTimeout(function() { defer.resolve(); }, 1000);

       return defer.promise;
   };
});
```

I'm using pit so I can have a 1 second delay to allow angular to update the view but it seems that the anonymous function in the setTimeout never gets called. The promise doesn't get fulfilled and the test times out. As Jest uses Jasmine 1.3.0 I've also tried using runs() and waitsFor() but I get the same result.

Comment: Always times out, with runs and waitsFor too. Always. No exception. (on AJAX calls)

Answer (score 2):

Battling this too, but have solved it in my case.  The key problem is that jest hijacks your timers and puts them in a queue that never gets run unless you explicitly do so.

try changing

```
return runTest()
.then(..
```

to

```
queued = runTest(); // run it... jest will hijack your internal timer
jest.runAllTimers(); // kick the timer to get it unstuck...
return queued.then(... // return the promise, having forced the internal timers to run
```

Actually, it's not that this command (jest.runAllTimers) will start the timers, it's that it will run what's inside the timer - so you skip the waiting, which can be nice for making your tests run faster.

useful background to be found here:
https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/timer-mocks.html#content

and here:
https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#jest-runalltimers